# Saber en que parte se hizo click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando un reproductor propio, lo que me falta es poder moverme por el video con click's en la barra de progreso, aqui la barra de progreso:

```
<player-progress-bar>
    <div style='width:100%'>
        <div class='hr-yt-played' style='width: 0%;'/>
        <div class='hr-yt-loaded' style='width: 0%;'/>          
    </div>                                      
</player-progress-bar>
```

¿Se puede saber con jQuery o javascript en que parte de la barra de progreso se hizo click?. Gracias

Comment: Patricio, tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. Te recomiendo que puedas editarla y poner un ejemplo del codigo que estas usando. Si necesitas ayuda ve este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Si no lo haces, es posible que tu pregunta sea puesta en espera o sea cerrada.

Comment: Editado. Gracias

Comment: ¿Te refieres a saber en qué **momento** (minuto, segundo...) se hizo clic en la barra de progreso?

Comment: Hola Cedano, no, a saber en que PARTE de la barra se hizo click (puede ser porcentaje). Gracias

Comment: es lo que quieres? http://jsfiddle.net/wqr7S/4/

Comment: Si SR!. Gracias Jack voy a probarlo

Comment: @JackNavaRow añade una respuesta con el código y no sólo un comentario con un enlace a la solución. La búsqueda no funciona con comentarios y los enlaces se rompen

Answer (score 1):

Debes de calcular el click  aqui un ejemplo:

```js
function doFirst(){
 barSize=600;
 myMovie=document.getElementById('myMovie');
 playButton=document.getElementById('playButton');
 bar=document.getElementById('defaultBar');
 progressBar=document.getElementById('progressBar');
 
 playButton.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
 bar.addEventListener('click', clickedBar, false);
}

function playOrPause() {
 if (!myMovie.paused && !myMovie.ended){
  myMovie.pause();
  playButton.innerHTML='Play';
  window.clearInterval(updateBar);
 } else {
  myMovie.play();
  playButton.innerHTML='Pause';
  updateBar=setInterval(update, 500);
 }
}

function update() {
 if (!myMovie.ended) {
  var size=parseInt(myMovie.currentTime*barSize/myMovie.duration);
  progressBar.style.width=size+'px';
 } else {
  progressBar.style.width='0px';
  playButton.innerHTML='Play';
  window.clearInterval(updateBar);
 }
}

function clickedBar(e){
 if(!myMovie.paused && !myMovie.ended){
  var mouseX=e.pageX-bar.offsetLeft;
  var newtime=mouseX*myMovie.duration/barSize;
  myMovie.currentTime=newtime;
  progressBar.style.width=mouseX+'px';
 }
}
window.addEventListener('load',doFirst,false);
```

```css
body {
 text-align: center;
}
 
header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup {
 display: block;
}
#skin {
 width:700px;
 margin:10px auto;
 padding:5px;
 background:red;
 border:4px solid black;
 border-radius:10px;
}
nav {
 margin: 5px 0px;
}
#buttons {
 float:left;
 width:70px;
 height:22px;
}
#defaultBar {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 width:600px;
 height:16px;
 padding:4px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 background:yellow;
}
#progressBar {
 position:absolute;
 width:0px;
 height:16px;
 background:blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="skin">
 <video id="myMovie" width="640" height="360">
  <source src="http://zencoder-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/trailer_test.mp4"/>
 </video>
 <nav>
  <div id="buttons">
   <button type="button" id="playButton">Play</button>
  </div>
  <div id="defaultBar">
   <div id="progressBar"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </nav>
</section>
```